# How to build WSO2 WSF/PHP 2.1.0 for FreeBSD 8.1?

Tags: php, build, freebsd, wso2

I have a problem with building WSO2 WSF/PHP on my FreeBSD 8.1. It seems that something broken in the source.

I check all prerequisites then run `./configure && make` and receive next error:

```
Making all in platforms/unix
/usr/local/bin/bash ../../../libtool --tag=CC    --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -I../../../include  -I../../../include/platforms  -I../../../include/platforms/unix     -g -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -ansi -Wall -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT uuid_gen_unix.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/uuid_gen_unix.Tpo -c -o uuid_gen_unix.lo uuid_gen_unix.c
mkdir .libs
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -I../../../include -I../../../include/platforms -I../../../include/platforms/unix -g -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -ansi -Wall -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -MT uuid_gen_unix.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/uuid_gen_unix.Tpo -c uuid_gen_unix.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/uuid_gen_unix.o
uuid_gen_unix.c: In function 'axutil_uuid_get_mac_addr':
uuid_gen_unix.c:332: error: 'SIOCGARP' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

After googling I found an advice to configure with `./configure 'CPPFLAGS=-DHAVE_GETIFADDRS'`. After that `make` command almost finished but die at the end with following information:

```
gcc -g -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -ansi -Wall -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -o .libs/test test.o  ../../axiom/src/om/.libs/libaxis2_axiom.so ../../util/src/.libs/libaxutil.so ../src/.libs/libneethi.so /usr/home/alisachenko/src/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/axis2c/axiom/src/om/.libs/libaxis2_axiom.so /usr/home/alisachenko/src/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/axis2c/axiom/src/parser/guththila/.libs/libaxis2_parser.so /usr/home/alisachenko/src/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/axis2c/guththila/src/.libs/libguththila.so /usr/home/alisachenko/src/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/axis2c/util/src/.libs/libaxutil.so -lpthread -lz  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/wsf_c/lib
../../util/src/.libs/libaxutil.so: undefined reference to `ftime'
```

What should I do to completely build WSO2 on my FreeBSD?

**UPD1**
Building after `./configure 'CPPFLAGS=-DHAVE_GETIFADDRS' 'LDFLAGS=-lcompat'`

```
gcc -shared   -Wl,--whole-archive ../src/platforms/unix/.libs/libaxis2_unix.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lcompat -lpthread -lz  -Wl,-soname -Wl,libaxutil.so.4 -o .libs/libaxutil.so.4
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libcompat.a(ftime.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/libcompat.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

**UPD2**
Building after `./configure CPPFLAGS='-fPIC -DHAVE_GETIFADDRS' 'LDFLAGS=-lcompat'`

```
gcc -shared  .libs/hash.o .libs/allocator.o .libs/env.o .libs/error.o .libs/stream.o .libs/log.o .libs/string.o .libs/string_util.o .libs/qname.o .libs/array_list.o .libs/linked_list.o .libs/utils.o .libs/dir_handler.o .libs/file_handler.o .libs/class_loader.o .libs/network_handler.o .libs/file.o .libs/uuid_gen.o .libs/thread_pool.o .libs/property.o .libs/types.o .libs/param.o .libs/param_container.o .libs/dll_desc.o .libs/url.o .libs/stack.o .libs/generic_obj.o .libs/base64.o .libs/uri.o .libs/date_time.o .libs/base64_binary.o .libs/properties.o .libs/http_chunked_stream.o .libs/rand.o .libs/date_time_util.o .libs/version.o .libs/duration.o .libs/frame.o .libs/stomp.o .libs/md5.o .libs/digest_calc.o -Wl,--whole-archive ../src/platforms/unix/.libs/libaxis2_unix.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lcompat -lpthread -lz  -Wl,-soname -Wl,libaxutil.so.4 -o .libs/libaxutil.so.4
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libcompat.a(ftime.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/libcompat.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/wsf_c/axis2c/util/src.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
./configure 'CPPFLAGS=-DHAVE_GETIFADDRS LDFLAGS==-lcompat'
```

Comment: Unfortunately your configuration wasn't help me to build wso2. Updated question.

Comment: As it says, recompile with -fPIC (add -fPIC to CPPFLAGS)

Comment: It seems that I should recompile libcompat with -fPIC? How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. You shouldn't recompile libcompat, just add -fPIC to CPPFLAGS: ./configure 'CPPFLAGS="-fPIC -DHAVE_GETIFADDRS" LDFLAGS==-lcompat'

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help me. But you recommendation doesn't bring me the result. See UPD2. I'm losing hope to build this source.

Comment: Can this problem be related to the platform? (relocation R_X86_64_32 can not be used ...)I have FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE for amd64 platform.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that there is libcompat.a, but no libcompat.so. The .a libs are built without -fPIC and this causes error. I would suggest you to recompile libcompat with -fPIC, but you need system sources in /usr/src for that. See this thread - http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=21456

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'll give this instruction to our administrator. Probably he allows me to recompile libcompat for development environment, but for production environment this can be impossible...

Comment: If you'd able to compile your software against libcompat.a, you will be able to copy compiled binaries to your production server and it should work. Also, i saw binary download on WSO's site, you can try this too, but i suspect, you will need linux_enable="YES" in /etc/rc.conf

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to run WSO2 on various FreeBSD AMD64 <del>without success</del>.
I am compiling WSO2 in jail built on top of ezjail.
Since recompilation of libcompat is required I did it in "main" system. All the rest is done in the jail.

1. In main system (without jail) I recompiled libcompat (/usr/src/lib/libcompat) with -fPIC in makefile, so now the line looks like that:

   CFLAGS+=-fPIC -DLIBC_SCCS -DSYSLIBC_SCCS -I${.CURDIR}/../libc/locale

   [root@system /usr/src/lib/libcompat]# make install
   install -C -o root -g wheel -m 444   libcompat.a /usr/lib
   install -C -o root -g wheel -m 444   libcompat_p.a /usr/lib
2. Then
   I copied  libcompat.a and libcompat_p.a into basejail and switched to jail where I made a compilation

I found this: http://bsd.dischaos.com/2008/05/14/wso-web-services-framework-on-freebsd/
which inspired me.
I modified wsf_c/axis2c/util/src/platforms/unix/uuid_gen_unix.c and added
    #include < sys/param.h>
(I put      ^^^^ space here because I it was wrongly parsed by stackoverflow portal)

3 . Then I modified configure.m4 and I put the following path
        PHP_ADD_INCLUDE(/usr/local/include/libxml2/libxml) replacing the original one

4 . Then still having problems with compilation I added these environment variables
    export CPATH=/usr/local/include:/usr/local/include/libxml2:/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl::/usr/local/ssl/include
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

5 . And finally I managed to compile without errors

./configure "CPPFLAGS=-fPIC -DHAVE_GETIFADDRS" "LDFLAGS=-lcompat"
 make
 make install

<del>My test jail on remote server doesnt have the web interface available yet and thus I couldn't test this installation on samples provided, but I am pretty sure that I would succeed since there were no errors during make nor during make install.</del>
Php -m shows wsf module without any segfaults.
Samples are also working fine. <del>I can't get wsdls yet, but it is rather matter of time.</del>
The important problem you may face is openssl. It must be in ver 0.9.8 at least if I recall correctly. I am using 1.x. though
Although this setup is working fine on Freebsd 8.x I was unable to have it working on FreeBSD 6.x. On 6.x I finally built WSO2 successfully, but got segfaults when included wsf.so in php configuration ... then I gave up on 6.x and focused on freebsd 8.x where it seems to work fine ... just starting to do some programming with this module.